# How make textview clickable and open wifi password popup if protected?

Tags: android, passwords, textview, android-wifi, clickable

i've created a list of the wifi connections. This list is inside a textview. How can i make the textview clickable and onclick over a connection open the popup to insert the password if protected? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a whole inside a textview, it will be very hard for you to detect onClick, maybe you should try using a standard ListView with an adapter. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) you will find an easy tutorial.

set an adapter to a listview like this one:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/networks_list"
    style="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```

Inside the adapter inflate something like the following, add elements as needed:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/net_name"
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Medium.Inverse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
```

Comment: Thanks, so do you think is better create a listview of the connections?

Comment: Well that or a list of textviews (with an adapter) if you prefer, but use different views for each connection. Added part of the code i use for this same functionality.